# Bump version number of framework

Tags: ios, xcode, frameworks

I am building a framework in Xcode 6, following (more or less) the tutorial here: https://medium.com/@syshen/create-an-ios-universal-framework-148eb130a46c

The major change is I change the mach-o setting to static library so I can use the framework for both iOS 7 and iOS 8...

Now, I'd like to consistently maintain the version number of the framework. Is there any best-practice way to do this?

When creating a framework in Xcode 6, the below lines are created:

```
//! Project version number for Myframework.
FOUNDATION_EXPORT double MyframeworkVersionNumber;

//! Project version string for Myframework.
FOUNDATION_EXPORT const unsigned char MyframeworkVersionString[];
```

How do we populate these with real values? The version would increase by 1 for every build, or somethin similar.

Answer (score 4):

One can change the value of `MyframeworkVersionNumber` in *Build Settings > Versioning > Current Project Version*.